# ¿Se puede llenar un JTable con datos de dos tablas distintas de una base de datos?

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos, jtable

Tengo una base de datos con diferentes tablas. Necesito llenar un JTable con datos de dos tablas diferentes cuando se cumpla una determinada condicion.

[image: Base de datos]

Esa seria mi base de datos, necesitaria que se muestre en la tabla todos los datos de **"infoa**" y de **"multimedios"** cuando el campo *Laboratorio* sea igual a un determinado numero, por ejemplo, en el caso de que **Laboratorio = 107**, se debe mostrar la o las filas de **multimedios** e **infoa** donde **Laboratorio = 107.** Espero haber sido claro.

Este es mi codigo:

```
public void mostrarDatos(String laboratorio){
               
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        PreparedStatement pst1 = null;
        
        DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
        jTableLaboratorios.setModel(modelo);
        
        
        try{
            Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/reportes","root","");
            String codigosql = "";
            String codigosql1 = "";
            
            if(laboratorio.equals("")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"No se ingreso un laboratorio");
            }else{
                codigosql = "SELECT ID, Nombre, Apellido, Reporte, PC, Reporte2, Año, Laboratorio FROM infoa WHERE Laboratorio LIKE '%" + laboratorio + "%'";
                codigosql1 = "SELECT ID, Nombre, Apellido, Reporte, PC, Reporte2, Año, Laboratorio FROM quimica WHERE Laboratorio LIKE '%" + laboratorio + "%'";
            }
            
             pst = cn.prepareStatement(codigosql);
             pst1 = cn.prepareStatement(codigosql1);
             
             ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
             ResultSet rs1 = pst1.executeQuery();
             
             ResultSetMetaData rsMD = rs.getMetaData();
             ResultSetMetaData rsMD1 = rs1.getMetaData();
             
            int cantidadColumnas = rsMD.getColumnCount();

            modelo.addColumn("ID"); 
            modelo.addColumn("Nombre");
            modelo.addColumn("Apellido");
            modelo.addColumn("Reporte");
            modelo.addColumn("PC");
            modelo.addColumn("Reporte2");
            modelo.addColumn("Año");
            modelo.addColumn("Laboratorio");
             
             while(rs.next() || rs1.next()){
                 
                Object[] filas = new Object[cantidadColumnas]; 

                for (int i = 0; i < cantidadColumnas; i++) { 
                    filas[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1); 
                    
                }

                modelo.addRow(filas); 
             }
            
        }catch(Exception e){
            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Hubo un error al procesaro los datos, contacte con el administrador");
            System.out.println("El error es:  " + e);
        }
```

En el intente crear dos elementos ResultSet pero no funciono y lei que tampoco se puede hacer. El metodo recibe como parametro el numero de laboratorio desde un jTextField en otra ventana.

Comment: Hola @nicodiez, siento decirte que en ésta comunidad no se realizan las tareas de nadie. Aquí lo que hacemos es ayudar, asesorar, mejorar, evaluar, corregir o auditar el código que uno tenga realizado y le impida seguir por errores, por dudas o por desconocimiento en las pasos siguientes, pero nunca completar una tarea desde cero. Si tienes código de tu ejercicio pégalo como texto y sobre él, podríamos empezar a trabajar. Un saludo

Comment: Codigo agregado

Comment: Para crear un segundo resultSet, tienes que cerrar el primero, no se pueden tener abiertos dos a la vez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ver como te puedo ayudar, es una idea por encima, pues no puedo hacer pruebas sin tener tu código con los result y demás

```
try{
        Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/reportes","root","");
        String codigosql = "";
        
        if(laboratorio.equals("")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"No se ingreso un laboratorio");
        }else{
            codigosql = "SELECT ID, Nombre, Apellido, Reporte, PC, Reporte2, Año, Laboratorio FROM infoa WHERE Laboratorio LIKE '%" + laboratorio + "%'";
        }
        
         pst = cn.prepareStatement(codigosql);
         
         ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
         
         ResultSetMetaData rsMD = rs.getMetaData();
         
        int cantidadColumnas = rsMD.getColumnCount();

        modelo.addColumn("ID"); 
        modelo.addColumn("Nombre");
        modelo.addColumn("Apellido");
        modelo.addColumn("Reporte");
        modelo.addColumn("PC");
        modelo.addColumn("Reporte2");
        modelo.addColumn("Año");
        modelo.addColumn("Laboratorio");
         
         while(rs.next() {
             
            Object[] filas = new Object[cantidadColumnas]; 

            for (int i = 0; i < cantidadColumnas; i++) { 
                filas[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1); 
                
            }

            modelo.addRow(filas); 

           rs.clase();
           rsMD.close();
           
        String codigosql1 = "";
        
        if(laboratorio.equals("")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"No se ingreso un laboratorio");
        }else{
            codigosql1 = "SELECT ID, Nombre, Apellido, Reporte, PC, Reporte2, Año, Laboratorio FROM quimica WHERE Laboratorio LIKE '%" + laboratorio + "%'";
        }
        
         pst1 = cn.prepareStatement(codigosql1);
         
         ResultSet rs1 = pst1.executeQuery();
         
         ResultSetMetaData rsMD1 = rs1.getMetaData();
         
        int cantidadColumnas1 = rsMD1.getColumnCount();

        modelo.addColumn("ID"); 
        modelo.addColumn("Nombre");
        modelo.addColumn("Apellido");
        modelo.addColumn("Reporte");
        modelo.addColumn("PC");
        modelo.addColumn("Reporte2");
        modelo.addColumn("Año");
        modelo.addColumn("Laboratorio");
         
         while(rs1.next()){
             
            Object[] filas1 = new Object[cantidadColumnas1]; 

            for (int i = 0; i < cantidadColumnas1; i++) { 
                filas1[i] = rs1.getObject(i + 1); 
                
            }

            modelo.addRow(filas1); 

         }
```

Ahora tendrías dos array de objetos filas y filas1 con los que tendrías que interactuar en función de lo que deseas

No si se vas pillando lo que intento explicar. O sea, los dos resultset no los puedes abrir de forma simultánea, primero tienes que abrir y ejecutar uno, cerrarlo y luego abrir y ejecutar el segundo

Ambos resultset puedes o bien almacenarlos en dos arrays de objetos diferentes, o incluso añadir el segundo resulset al array del objetos del primer resultset

No se si me he sabido explicar